# FFmpeg auto rotates video when only copying stream

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, codec

I am facing this issue while converting mp4 (portrait) file to mkv. The command I'm using

`ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy test.mkv`

The output video is 90 degree counter clockwise rotated. Its because I think the side data is being removed.

`Side data:
 displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees`

Input file `test.mp4` info

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-02-23T11:18:50.000000Z
    com.android.version: 8.0.0
  Duration: 00:00:25.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12270 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 12005 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-02-23T11:18:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-23T11:18:50.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Rotated output file `test.mkv` info

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MAJOR_BRAND     : mp42
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isommp42
    COM.ANDROID.VERSION: 8.0.0
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12265 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ROTATE          : 90
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandle
      DURATION        : 00:00:25.866000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandle
      DURATION        : 00:00:25.813000000
```

Converting the rotated mkv to mp4 again works fine and I get the portrait file. The displaymatrix side data appears again in the file info.

Also converting the same mp4 file to m4v by copying the stream works fine.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902474/how-to-disable-libav-autorotate-display-matrix) they solved it for c++. I am working on android and using ffmpeg android wrapper to use the ffmpeg library. Is there any ffmpeg flag to handle this situation?

Comment: Is it ok with you to *not* use ffmpeg?

Comment: If its usable in android then yes. @Xilpex

Comment: Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why this works in `MP4`/`MOV` is because for this format the display matrices are stored in the Movie Header (`mvhd`) and Track Header (`tkhd`) atoms.

Example layout for `mvhd` showing the matrix structure:

[image]

Source: [Apple QuickTime File Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-32947)

When the stream is muxed in `MKV` the matrices are lost and the muxer falls back to adding the `ROTATE` metadata entry instead. You can see this in your `ffprobe` output. If the stream is then muxed back in a `MP4` the metadata information is used to create the matrix (if you pass `-map_metadata -1` when creating the `MKV` the information is lost and the conversion no longer works).

On the player side there's no guarantee that it will look for and apply the rotation specified in the `ROTATE` tag. If you want to use `MKV` with the proper orientation you will have to re-encode, otherwise stick with `MP4`.